# Clone a object while maintaining derived type from an extension method

Tags: c#, clone

Not sure if my vernacular is correct so bear with me on this.

I have a public interface being used in plugins, the classes that implement this interface I want to be clone-able while maintaining their declaring type and all properties therein.

I am aware of `ICloneable` and that I could simply implement that into my interface but I do not want to pass off the requirement to implement the interface onto the plugin developers and want to control it myself.

Also worth noting that it needs to be lightweight and does not need to be deep. I also do not know anything of the declared type at design time other than it implements my plugin interface, so I would need to cast it into its "unknown" source type.

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
    int commonProp {get;set;}
}

// This class and the properties therein are not known at design time
public myObj : ImyInterface
{
    int commonProp {get;set;}
    int uncommonProp {get;set;}
}
```

Then I need to call from my application somthing like:

```
// This is how I generally "activate my plugins"
ImyInterface obj = (ImyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Then elsewhere I need to clone its current state.
var ClonedObj = obj.clone();
```

I tried [this](http://www.extensionmethod.net/1706/csharp/object/clone-t), but it requires me knowing the type at design time.

Comment: if you *expect* it to be cloneable, then `ICloneable` seems a *reasonable* requirement to pass onwards. In the general case, cloning an unknown object is very awkward and brittle. You can *do it* (via `GetType()` and skipping the constructors via `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`, then forcefully setting the instance fields even if `private` and/or `readonly`) - but ... gah that's ugly

Comment: @MarcGravell For the purposes of streamlining I wanted to avoid the responsibility of creating cloning methods on to the plugin developer. It is however a last resort if there is no other way

Comment: well, why does it need to be cloned? what purpose would the clone serve vs the original?

Comment: @MarcGravell to keep an original prior to modifying properties.

Comment: you're making a lot of assumptions there; I could trivially create a type which - when shallow cloned - will propagate property changes to both instances. Basically, anything that acts as a flyweight or proxy etc. Your plan is IMO fundamentally brittle.

Comment: @MarcGravell You could? Then care to share how?

Comment: will do when back at a computer, sure - only needs a few lines

Comment: @Woobles, have at least tried what I posted? If so, Is not that what you need? Because IMO from the title **Clone a object while maintaining derived type from an extension method** I think that it could meet your requirements. Marc Gravell is opining about your architecture and design, which is valid but think has nothing to do to the HOW TO DO what you want to do

Comment: DeepCloner has even a **ShallowClone();** method...

Comment: @taquion I'm worried about the performance penalty of that method, I will have to do a side by side test to see. Looking to get close to the performance of MemberwiseClone, but with the ability to put the method in an extension rather than inside the obj.

Comment: I would do a performance test too. Nevertheless you can see that the project site has already a couple of tables regarding performance behavior. Obviously the fastest way is to do it manually. This approach involves just **16 ns** accordingly to the mentioned table, while **ShallowClone** will take **64 ns**

Comment: @taquion That's not bad at all, assuming it fits my other requirements this may be the way to go. Will still do a side by side to ensure this also doesn't eat up a lot of CPU. But ive hung up my hat for the day so on my list for tomorrow.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a performance test and yet another better way to achieve the goal

Comment: @Wobbles sorry for the delay: life is complicated, but: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/72b046a01455d5fe800fddde83efe974 - a shallow clone will result in the property value being propagated between the two instances; a trivial clone is not possible because it will result in either a missing .ctor failure, or a null field failure

Comment: @MarcGravell I dont see any cloning there, only copying references.

Comment: @Wobbles the cloning part is the bit you are providing, remember? Now: imagine that you are given an `ISomeInterface` reference that happens to be a `CloneHell` instance. Now try to clone it. The problems are nuanced and various, yet that's a perfectly valid implementation of `ISomeInterface`

Comment: @MarcGravell That doesn't answer anything for me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [DeepCloner](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner), which is available from NuGet. I think this library implements just exactly what you need and as **extension methods**. It is also Open Source and hosted in GitHub, so if you want to add more features or just to know how it works you can check the code.

From the project site:

> Also, there is no requirement to specify object type for cloning. Object can be casted to inteface or as an abstract object, you can clone array of ints as abstract Array or IEnumerable, even null can be cloned without any errors.

I made this sample to show how it works:

An interface and a class implementing this interface:

```
 interface IPluginInterface { }

    class Foo:IPluginInterface
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        public Foo()
        {
            SomeInt = 42;
            SomeString = "SomeString";
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"SomeInt: {SomeInt}. SomeString: {SomeString}";
    }
```

Then in main add **using Force.DeepCloner;** and...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPluginInterface foo = new Foo();
            IPluginInterface fooWithActivator = (IPluginInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo));
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
            var cloneOfFoo = foo.DeepClone();
            var cloneOfFooWithActivator = fooWithActivator.DeepClone();

            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFoo);
            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFoo == foo);
            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFoo.GetType());

            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFooWithActivator);
            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFooWithActivator == foo);
            Console.WriteLine(cloneOfFooWithActivator.GetType());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And the output:

[image]

EDIT>>>> Based on your concerns about performance I have made some tests and also find another and better way to achieve what you want.

The better way approach involves calling **MemberwiseClone** method using a mixture of **Reflection, Delegates and Jon Skeet**. The idea is to convert the methodinfo instance into a delegate, more info can be found in [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) post by Jon Skeet.

Here is main():

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int howManyTimes = 10000000;
            IPluginInterface foo = new Foo(true);
            foo.ShallowCloneWithDeepClonerLibrary(howManyTimes);
            foo.ShallowCloneWithReflection(howManyTimes);
            ((Foo)foo).ShallowCloneWithMemberWiseClone(howManyTimes);
            foo.ShallowCloneWithDelegatesAndReflection(howManyTimes);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

As you may notice we are testing four approaches for shallow cloning:

- DeepCloner library
- Exposing MemberWiseClone directly. (Not suitable for your case)
- Using MethodInfo.Invoke where MethodInfo is MemberwiseClone
- Using delegate

This is the code of all 4 methods (which are extension methods):

```
public static void ShallowCloneWithDeepClonerLibrary(this object obj, int times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Performing {times.ToString("##,###")} cloning operations with DeepCloner's ShallowClone method:");
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < times - 1; i++) obj.ShallowClone();
        var clone = obj.ShallowClone();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total milliseconds elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Are both the same: {obj == clone}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cloned object: {Environment.NewLine}{clone}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }

    public static void ShallowCloneWithMemberWiseClone(this Foo obj, int times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Performing {times.ToString("##,###")} cloning operations wiht MemberwiseClone:");
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < times - 1; i++) obj.Clone();
        var clone = obj.Clone();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total milliseconds: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Are both the same: {obj == clone}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cloned object: {Environment.NewLine}{clone}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }

    public static void ShallowCloneWithDelegatesAndReflection(this object obj, int times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Performing {times.ToString("##,###")} cloning operations by encapsulating MemberwiseClone method info in a delegate:");
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var clone = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var memberWiseClone = type.GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var memberWiseCloneDelegate =
            (Func<object, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, object>), memberWiseClone);
        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) clone = memberWiseCloneDelegate(obj);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total milliseconds: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Are both the same: {obj == clone}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cloned object: {Environment.NewLine}{clone}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }

    public static void ShallowCloneWithReflection(this object obj, int times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Performing {times.ToString("##,###")} cloning operations manually with reflection and MemberwiseClone:");
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var memberWiseClone = type.GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var clone = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        for (var i = 0; i < times - 1; i++)
            clone = memberWiseClone.Invoke(obj, null);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total milliseconds: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Are both the same: {obj == clone}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cloned object: {Environment.NewLine}{clone}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
```

And the results in milliseconds of making 10,000,000 cloning operations with each one:

- DeepCloner: **791**
- MemberwiseClone directly: **463**
- MemberwiseClone with MethodInfo.Invoke: **2000**
- MemberwiseClone via Delegate: **465**

So, we have a winner! Unfortunately the winner is not suitable for your case due to the fact that implies exposing MemberwiseClone in the class. But... We have a tremendous second place!!

Here is the output:

[image]